# Ambiguous tag "design"

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-block-request

Browsing [design](/questions/tagged/design) presents 8937 questions, ranging from web design to database design to code design and beyond.

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/69238

Top related tags (not all inclusive):

- [design-patterns](/questions/tagged/design-patterns) (9,394)
- [database-design](/questions/tagged/database-design) (8007)
- [domain-driven-design](/questions/tagged/domain-driven-design) (1720)
- [web-design](/questions/tagged/web-design) (1494)
- [language-design](/questions/tagged/language-design) (742)
- [class-design](/questions/tagged/class-design) (771)
- [designer](/questions/tagged/designer) (524)
- [software-design](/questions/tagged/software-design) (288)
- [good-design](/questions/tagged/good-design) (254!) ...I did not find the "bad design" tag

Other related usage:

- [api-design](/questions/tagged/api-design) (162)
- [code-design](/questions/tagged/code-design) (46)
- [interface-design](/questions/tagged/interface-design) (24)
- [design-choices](/questions/tagged/design-choices) (2)
- [url-design](/questions/tagged/url-design) (5)
- [table-less-design](/questions/tagged/table-less-design) (4)
- [design-problem](/questions/tagged/design-problem) (36)
- [gui-design](/questions/tagged/gui-design) (15)
- [ui-design](/questions/tagged/ui-design) (54)
- [design-consideration](/questions/tagged/design-consideration) (8)
- [designers](/questions/tagged/designers) (8)
- [hardware-design](/questions/tagged/hardware-design) (3)
- [compiler-design](/questions/tagged/compiler-design) (43)
- [interaction-design](/questions/tagged/interaction-design) (12)
- [primary-key-design](/questions/tagged/primary-key-design) (17)
- [design-tools](/questions/tagged/design-tools) (7)
- [object-design](/questions/tagged/object-design) (8)
- [service-design](/questions/tagged/service-design) (7)

This is my first time caring about the fate of a tag, but "design" seems much too broad to be useful when there are plenty of more explicit alternatives.

I'm not sure what the protocol is or what can even be done. Should "design" be blacklisted, or should some of these tags be pruned or merged?

Comment: sorry, I'm giving up for today; being too blind. I voted to close that question as I think it's inappropriate; as is a `design` tag so +1

Comment: [tag:designer] is probably about UI designer software, which isn't directly related.